# How can I send an optional request header to my request using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, content-type, rtk-query

I am using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query to construct my API calls to receive data. I have one that I am generally sending as  a normal request with `'Content-type: 'application/json'` as the default header, but I want to be able to send in a parameter to change that header to be `'Content-type: 'text/csv'` when I need (I don't want anything else about the request to be different so I want that header to be dynamic). How do I do this?

Here is where I create my base API:

```js
export const baseApi = createApi({
  refetchOnFocus: true,
  baseQuery: retry(
    fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: API_BASE_URL,
      prepareHeaders: async (headers) => {
        const token = await getAuth0KeyAccessToken();
        if (!token) {
          console.warn('Token not set');
        }
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        if (isCsv) { // <-- `isCsv` is currently undefined. How can I pass it in? 
          headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        }
        return headers;
      },
    }),
    { maxRetries: 2 },
  ),
  tagTypes: ['Reporting', etc],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Here is where I call this base API:

```js
getCSV: builder.query<any, IReportingQuery>({
  providesTags: ['Reporting'],
  transformResponse: (response: { data: ReportingDP[] | ReportingDP }, meta, arg) =>
    arg.group_by
      ? response.data
      : Array.isArray(response.data)
        ? response.data.sort(dayComparator)
        : [response.data],
  query: (body) => ({
    url: '/api/v3/reporting', method: 'POST', body
  }),
}),
```

Where in this request can I send the `isCsv` boolean to my baseAPI?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd specify this value in the endpoint's [`extraOptions`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#extraoptions) property.

> ### extraOptions
>
> *(optional)*
>
> Passed as the third argument to the supplied baseQuery function

The [`prepareHeaders`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#prepareheaders) is passed two arguments, the `headers` object and the `api` object that has an `extra` property.

> ```
> type prepareHeaders = (
>   headers: Headers,
>   api: {
>     getState: () => unknown
>     extra: unknown // <-- this
>     endpoint: string
>     type: 'query' | 'mutation'
>     forced: boolean | undefined
>   }
> ) => Headers | void
> ```

Your code:

```js
getCSV: builder.query<any, IReportingQuery>({
  providesTags: ['Reporting'],
  transformResponse: (response: { data: ReportingDP[] | ReportingDP }, meta, arg) =>
    arg.group_by
      ? response.data
      : Array.isArray(response.data)
        ? response.data.sort(dayComparator)
        : [response.data],
  query: (body) => ({
    url: '/api/v3/reporting', method: 'POST', body
  }),
  extraOptions: {
    isCsv: true, // <-- pass in extraOptions
  },
}),
```

```js
export const baseApi = createApi({
  refetchOnFocus: true,
  baseQuery: retry(
    fetchBaseQuery({
      baseUrl: API_BASE_URL,
      prepareHeaders: async (headers, api) => {
        const token = await getAuth0KeyAccessToken();

        if (!token) {
          console.warn('Token not set');
        }

        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

        if (api.extra.isCsv) { // <-- read from api.extra
          headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        }

        return headers;
      },
    }),
    { maxRetries: 2 },
  ),
  tagTypes: ['Reporting', etc],
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```